# Link not working Vbs asp

Tags: html, vbscript, asp-classic

my latest learning project was a counting asp, using VBscript.
While i got mit for loops correct and my if, deciding if it's the loop for counting up or counting down, the Link with the button, to go back to the HTML default page, that has a choice of links to other ASP sites.
It's saved in the same folder and the name in the link is spelled correct.

If there is no user entry, and i klick the link i get a type missmatch error at the secon loop that counts down. Ifit has run once, then nohtings happening.

Why is this so?

```
<form action = "countdown.asp" method = "get">
   <h1 align = "center">Dies ist ein Zähler!<h1>
    <table border = "1" align = "center">
      <tr>
        <td>
          Bitte einen Startwert eingeben.
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type = "number" name = "f_start" value = "<%=l_start%>"
        </td>
        <td width = "100">
          &nbsp;
        </td>
        <td>
          Bitte einen Zielwert eingeben.
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type = "number" name = "f_goal" value = "<%=l_goal%>"
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type = "submit" value = "Go!" \>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          Gez&auml;hlte Zahlen:
        </td>
        <td>
          <%
            if request.querystring(("f_start")) < request.querystring(("f_goal")) then 
              For i = l_start To l_goal
                response.write("" & i & ",<br />")
              Next
            else
                For i = l_start To l_goal step -1
                response.write("" & i & ",<br />")
              Next
            end if
          %>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
</form>
  <br>
    <table align = "center">
      <tr>
         <td>
          <a href = "default.html">
            <button>
              Zur&uuml;ck zur Auswahl
            </button>
          </a>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
```

Comment: This is not asp.net, so I change the tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it using form.

```
<form action = default.html>
  <br>
    <table align = "center">
      <tr>
         <td>
          <a href = "default.html">
            <button>
              Zur&uuml;ck zur Auswahl
            </button>
          </a>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

`<a href="/">Link</a>`

This will send you back to the index.html page.

But if you are wanting to go to default.html specifically you need to make sure the link to the page is correct. You need to make sure that the path is relative to where the page is from the root.

Edit: The best way to check if the path is correct, is if you have visual studio drag and drop the page into the work space, visual studio creates the link for you, then you can simply adjust it to your needs.

Comment: I use the same link, exactly as shown here on four other sites and it works perfectly, and both the default page, and the counddown page are in the same Intranet folder. I gues somehting is maybe wrong with my Syntax on this page.

Comment: I see nothing with the syntax of the link, it will most likely be the path to the page.

Comment: Have you tried putting the link outside of the table?

Comment: Yes doesn't work. My guess is that the greater than operator could be interpreted a non closed html tag bracket. could this be possible?

Comment: The best way to check the link is working correctly is to try and link to any webpage. If this works then it is the path to the .html page. `<a href="https://www.google.com">Link</a>`

Comment: Try this: `<button type="button" onclick="location.href='default.html'">Test</button>`

Comment: Thanks for al the suggestions.